# C# - get object name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Sorry about unspecific title, not entirely sure how to describe it

I have a custom list of lists for a menu. CatalogueMenu has an enumerator so I can loop through the colour lists in it

```
public class CatalogueMenu
{
    private List<List<MenuItem>> MenuList = new List<List<MenuItem>>();

    public List<MenuItem> Reds { get; private set; }
    public List<MenuItem> Blues { get; private set; }
    public List<MenuItem> Greens { get; private set; }
    public List<MenuItem> Yellows { get; private set; }

    public CatalogueMenu ()
    {
        Reds = new List<MenuItem>();
        Blues = new List<MenuItem>();
        Greens = new List<MenuItem>();
        Yellows = new List<MenuItem>();

        MenuList.Add(Reds);
        MenuList.Add(Blues);
        MenuList.Add(Greens);
        MenuList.Add(Yellows);
    }

    public IEnumerator<List<MenuItem>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.MenuList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC3 app I'm looping through the lists, but I also want to display the name of each list e.g

Blues
 - list
 - of
 - blues
Reds
 - list
 - of
 - reds

a) Can I get the list name from the actual list-object itself?
or
b) Do I have to create a custom class for the colour list so it contains a string for the name, and a list as well

```
<ul>
@foreach (var itemList in Model)
 {
    <li class="listName">**@itemList.Name or something like that?**</li>
     foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(
                item.Name, 
                "Browse", 
                "Catalogue", 
                Request.QueryString.ToRouteValueDictionary().AddOrUpdate(**itemList.Name??**, item.ID),
                null)
        </li>
    }
 }
</ul>
```

Comment: You certainly can get the name of an object at runtime; that's called [reflection](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/). Still studying what the rest of your problem implies, though.

Comment: @Albert Perrien: No, an object doesn't have a name. You can use reflection to get the name of a property that contains a reference to the object, but only by looping through the properties and getting their values to compare them to the reference of the object.

Comment: @Albert: Assuming that "name" means "name of the variable that refers to it", I have to doubt both that it's possible and that it's meaningful. There is no such thing as the name of an object - for a given object, there's any number (including zero) of names referring to it. And finding them is extremely costy, by the way. That number is unrelated to the number of actual references to the object, by the way.

Comment: I see, I confused "name of object" with "type of object". There is no way to identify an individual object at runtime. Still mastering this C# stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a different way to get this, but the TypeDescriptor class (System.ComponentModel) will provide the information that you are looking for.

```
var names = new List<string>();
var menu = new CatalogueMenu();
var descriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(menu);

foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in descriptors)
{
    names.Add(descriptor.Name);
}
```

Names will now contain "Reds", "Blues", etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. This here was pretty much what I was looking for (was hoping I could do it more directly without building seperate list, but oh well). I guess I can probably build it into the CatalogueMenu so I can do CatalogueMenu.GetNames or something. Probably a little over the top but I'm having fun learning :)

Answer (score 0):

a)
No, you can't get the name from the list itself, because an object doesn't have a name. What you are looking for is the name of a variable that contains a reference to the list, and the list object has no reference back to the variables that contains references to it.

b)
There are different ways of solving that, but creating a custom class for the color list is a good solution, perhaps the best.